# Nginx error logs: what does "pagespeed: rollback gzip, explicit configuration in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:151" mean, and how can I fix it to use brotli?

Tags: linux, nginx, ubuntu, mod-pagespeed

I am running an Ubuntu 20.04 LEMP server with the pagespeed and brotli module for Nginx. In my `/var/log/nginx/error.log` I am seeing the following error:

```
2023/02/23 07:34:49 [info] 1553667#1553667: [ngx_pagespeed 1.15.0.0-8811] No threading detected. Own threads: 1 Rewrite, 1 Expensive Rewrite.
2023/02/23 07:34:49 [info] 1553667#1553667: pagespeed: rollback gzip, explicit configuration in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:151
```

What exactly does this mean? Does this mean nginx pagespeed is abandoning Brotli compression and rolling back to gzip? How can I fix things so that this error no longer appears, and ensure that the brotli module stays active using brotli compression even while the pagespeed module is active?

Comment: For the sake of completeness, what does your line 151 on `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` say?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is your answer:

> You can ignore that message, indeed it is just the module logging about it observing that gzip is already configured, and that it is backing out of any changes it was planning for.
> From: https://groups.google.com/g/ngx-pagespeed-discuss/c/Bm0hWfIZNz0